# How to return relative to request django

Tags: python, django

In my django project, I built a little like-button. The problem is, that I had it only when I take a detailed view on a post, and now want to put it on the home page, where multiple posts are shown. The problem the Like Function of the button returns to the detailed page, but I want to make the return dependent from the url where the like came from, so that I can just scroll ahead on the home page or what ever page am on, without being returned to another page. So here is my `views.py` Like function:

```
def PostLike(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post-detail', args=[str(pk)]))
```

So in a nutshell: how could I change my Like function so that I am returned to the page I liked from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns a Redirect, that's why you are redirected to the detail page.

If you want to stay on the same page after clicking 'Like' you could submit a request through Ajax and return a JsonResponse with a message or a value depending on what you get from the database query.

How to do this varies based on what JS library or framework you are using. Here is a simplistic JQuery example:

in views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def like_or_unlike(request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
            if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
                post.likes.remove(request.user)
                message = 'You unliked post ' + id
            else:
                post.likes.add(request.user)
                message = 'You liked post ' + id
        except:
            message = 'Error processing like for post ' + id

    else:
        message = 'You must be logged in to like a post.'

    return JsonResponse({ 'result': message })
```

in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("like/<id>/", views.like_or_unlike),
]
```

in template.html

```
<button class="{% if post.liked %}color-blue{% else %}color-white{% endif %}" 
id="post_{{ post.id|stringformat:"s" }}" 
onclick="postLike( '{{ post.id|stringformat:"s" }}' )"> Like this post </button>

<script>
  function postLike(id) {
    var element = "#post_" + id
    $.ajax({
      url: '/like/' + id,
      type: 'get',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if $(element).hasClass("color-white") {
          $(element).removeClass("color-white");
          $(element).addClass("color-blue");
        } else {
          $(element).removeClass("color-blue");
          $(element).addClass("color-white");
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: But in this case I do not need to include something like a likes proberty for my Post Model, do I?

Comment: And do I have to include the url `/postlike/` now?

Comment: Yes you need to have an url for the ajax call and point it to the view function, I have added to the answer. I assumed you already have a 'likes' property in your model, since you are using it in your code, if not  you should probably have one if you want to display the 'liked' status of a post in your template.

Comment: A one-to-one field wouldn't work, a post may be liked by many users and a user may like many posts. You could go with a many-to-many 'likes' field in your Posts model or a separate Likes model. There is an article here: https://medium.com/djangotube/django-like-and-dislike-buttons-model-design-like-youtube-f152b95e7f21

Comment: Oh thank so much! Nearly there! But... now, when I press the like button, there is a blank page with the label `result: "You liked post 26"`... what happened now...?

Comment: Remove the <form> tags just leave the button on its own.

Comment: omg. i still get an error Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function. Tried to find out, what it is... the internet says, I have only the slim version of jquery, but snippets that were recommended dont work... maybe you can help me?

Comment: Ah I just added src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" according to a stackanswer, so that the ajax error is now away... but now there is another error  postLike is not defined... maybe, because I defined it in the `base.html` template, that is the base for the others...?

Comment: Put the Ajax script on the page where it is used, load JQuery through base.html

Comment: Ok, now I defined `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` in the `base.html` template and dragged the complete `postLike` function over to the html file the button is in, but I am still getting the error, that ajax is not a function. One problem I am watching is that in the button there are three times quotation marks so that I am not sure if this is an error (red-marked as error) or if the programm handles this itself (not shown in the console): `onclick="postLike('{{ post.id|stringformat:'s' }}')"> {{ number_of_likes }} Like{{ number_of_likes|pluralize }}`

Comment: The "s" should be in double quotes like in the code example and it will be fine. You should use the full version  of jQuery, the slim version doesn't have the Ajax function. Why are you on an old version of jQuery?

Comment: Ok so I edited these things and now there is another error is appearing: `GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/postlike/26`: Not Found

Comment: It's not supposed to be "/postlike/" but "/like/", if you change it in the script you must change in urls.py as well.

Comment: ufff sorry didnt mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Ajax request for it so you don't even reload page. Just handle it in JavaScript.
Otherwise you can redirect base on request.referer value to go back to the view where click was made

Comment: So... I make a button connected to a JavaScript function, that adds 1 to the models proberty "likes" ... the problem is: how do I set the rules for this like function (you can only like one time, etc.)?

Comment: See answer below